# Kill the processes if it running for more than one hour bash script

Tags: ubuntu

i have this bash script that run python program in ubuntu server every 5 monites if not alredy running ,
i want to make it kill program if it running more tha one hour and re run it
any help

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f "/home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py"
then
    echo "script running"
    # Command when the script is runnung
else
    echo "script not running"
    /home/user/crawler/env/bin/python /home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py
fi
```

Comment: Use the `pgrep` command you already have to determine the Process ID and then use that PID with something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870 to determine how long that PID has been running and `kill` that PID if it has been running too long.

Comment: i tried this , but no output showing 
ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep -i "/home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py"
@diya

Comment: You could run the python script under control of the `timeout` command, so that it gets killed if it runs for more than an hour.

Comment: @larsks that perfect solution for me , can  u re write your commant as answer so i can  mark it as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `pgrep` to find the process, a simpler solution may be to run the Python script under the control of the [`timeout` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html)  (which is part of GNU `coreutils`). You can then limit the maximum runtime of your Python script to 1 hour:

```
timeout 1h /home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py
```

Comment: thanks that the perfect solution